# Why are dashboard lights sometimes delayed

Tags: electrical, toyota, headlight, lights, dashboard

After turning on the headlights during driving it sometimes takes a while for the dashboard and tail lights to come on.

I tested the tail light fuse which was good. Noticed that when the dash and tail lights work there’s an interior click but not when they don’t so this could be a sticky relay if only we could find where it is.

This is a RHD 2009 Toyota Corolla 1.8 hatch that otherwise starts and drives fine. The headlights themselves operate with no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved.  Turns out it's a known issue with poor electrical contact on the headlight stalk switch - these can be cleaned.  Credit goes to this YouTube video for explaining the fix which I applied yesterday.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qX5ABfOwOZU.